# Hybris: how to add my jsp tag inside another jsp tag which locates in another extention

Tags: java, jsp, jsp-tags, sap-commerce-cloud

I created addon and jsp tag, which is located at :
bin\custom\Myaddon\acceleratoraddon\web\webroot\WEB-INF\tags\desctop\product\productList.tag

Here is code of productList.tag:

```
 <%@ tag body-content="empty" trimDirectiveWhitespaces="true" %>
 <%@ attribute name="product" required="true" type="de.hybris.platform.commercefacades.product.data.ProductData" %>

 <%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
 <%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>
 <%@ taglib prefix="ycommerce" uri="http://hybris.com/tld/ycommercetags" %>


 <div class="addmybutton">
       <form id="add_to_list_form" action="${addToListUrl}" method="post">
        <input name="code" type="hidden" value="${product.code}"/>
        <input name="isPostponed" type="hidden" value="false"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="CSRFToken" value="${CSRFToken.token}">
        <button id="add_to_list_submit_button" type="submit" class="b-btn b-btn--red i-fs14"><spring:theme
                code="text.addToMyList"/></button>
    </form>
  </div>
```

**How i can make this jsp tag appear inside the jsp page (or any jsp tag) which locates in storefront?**

For instance, if I want to add my jsp tag to productLayout1Page.jsp (which automatically created when we create storefront extention).

Location of productLayout1Page.jsp:
bin\custom\myModule\myModulestorefront\web\webroot\WEB-INF\views\responsive\pages\product\productLayout1Page.jsp

Here is a code of productLayout1Page.jsp:

```
 <%@ page trimDirectiveWhitespaces="true"%>
 <%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
 <%@ taglib prefix="template" tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags/responsive/template"%>
 <%@ taglib prefix="cms" uri="http://hybris.com/tld/cmstags"%>
 <%@ taglib prefix="product" tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags/responsive/product"%>
```

```
</cms:pageSlot>
<product:productDetailsPanel />
<cms:pageSlot position="CrossSelling" var="comp" element="div" class="productDetailsPageSectionCrossSelling">
    <cms:component component="${comp}" element="div" class="productDetailsPageSectionCrossSelling-component"/>
</cms:pageSlot>

<cms:pageSlot position="Section2" var="comp" element="div" class="productDetailsPageSection2">
    <cms:component component="${comp}" element="div" class="productDetailsPageSection2-component"/>
</cms:pageSlot>

<cms:pageSlot position="Section3" var="comp" element="div" class="productDetailsPageSection3">
    <cms:component component="${comp}" element="div" class="productDetailsPageSection3-component"/>
</cms:pageSlot>
<cms:pageSlot position="UpSelling" var="comp" element="div" class="productDetailsPageSectionUpSelling">
    <cms:component component="${comp}" element="div" class="productDetailsPageSectionUpSelling-component"/>
</cms:pageSlot>
<product:productPageTabs />
<cms:pageSlot position="Section4" var="comp" element="div" class="productDetailsPageSection4">
    <cms:component component="${comp}" element="div" class="productDetailsPageSection4-component"/>
</cms:pageSlot>
```

I should add code only to my addon. All changes should appear on storefront only after `ant all`.

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Comment: thanks, I edited my question

Comment: Elena, check my answer below and let me know if any questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to edit html content of a page without making changes to the storefronts files, you have 2 options:

1. Use existing content slots and adding cms components/actions to them. You can create components/actions inside your addon and add those components to your content slot using impex/cms cockpit. This option is very limited since you are constrained to existing content slots. [more](https://wiki.hybris.com/display/R5T/Creating+New+CMS+Components)
2. Create a completely new page inside an addon and overwrite the page in your storefront. This option involes a lot of copying content from A to B and i would not recommend it.  If there is no really really good reason to use this option, consider option 1 or change the files in the storefont.
   [more](https://wiki.hybris.com/display/accdoc50to56/Customizing+the+Product+Details+Pages)

In a lot of cases it is almost inevitable to change the content of the jsp files in the storefront.

Answer (score 4):

Elena

1. First you need to place your tags under any sub folder in WEB-INF\tags. I see you already place there.
2. Second you need to import your tags in any other jsp or tags like below.

   `<%@ taglib prefix="myOwnTag" tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags/custom/folder/" %>`

   In the tagdir, Do not mention the tag name, just leave until the directory 
     it is in. So in your case this will be `<%@ taglib prefix="myOwnTag" 
     tagdir="WEB-INF\tags\desctop\product" %>`
3. use the tag like below whether in jsp or another tag

   `<prefix-mentioned-above:name-of-the-tag/>`

   In your case this will be

   `<myOwnTag:productList/>`

Check my code in the image.
I created an `year.tag` which i used in an `other.tag` which i used in `index.jsp` page.

[image: check my code here]

Hope this helps you how to use tags in jsp's and another tag's.

Comment: Kumar, thank you a lot for such detailed answer. But is this proper exactly for hybris platform? It really works within my addon. Let's I explain on your example: for instance, we need add to index.jsp (on your picture) another jsp tag (which will be located in another extention), but I am not able to write any code in index.jsp. I need to use some Hybris tools.

Comment: @Elena i have not worked on hybris but i think it should work the same way there too.